# Oracle: check if composite (!) foreign key exists

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

So I know the **table name**, the **two column names** that forms the composite primary key and I have to check programmatically (Oracle SQL function) if this foreign key exists.
If the foreign key exists, it's name is unpredictable because it's auto-generated (like SYS_C0075474), so I cannot rely on it.
I'm aware of the user_constraints table but it seems to lack the necessary information for me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are attempting to see if a value is in a table without knowing the value.  That would be difficult don't you think?

Comment: Why not just create the constraint **with** a name? That is highly recommended anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yeah, but if you are given a DB without known constraint names... :)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to need the [`[user|all|dba]_cons_columns` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1035.htm#i1575870).

Something like

```
SELECT constraint_name
  FROM user_cons_columns
 WHERE table_name = <<your table name>>
   AND column_name IN( <<your first column>>, <<your second column>> )
 GROUP BY constraint_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

will give you the name of the constraint that is defined on exactly those two columns.